# html form is being sent on reset button

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a problem with the html form.

This is my code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
  <input id="first_name"  type="text" name="first_name" size="30"/>
  <input id="company_name"  type="text" name="company_name" size="30"/>
  <input id="email"  type="text" name="email" size="30"/>
  <input type="image" align="middle" src="images/accept.png" alt="Submit" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="reset" type="image" src="images/reset.png" alt="Reset" align="middle" />
</form>
```

when I click any of this images my form is sent. How can I make this reset picture to only reset and not to send the form.

Comment: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/imagereset.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reset button is not a reset button. It has `type="image"`, it is server side image map.

When you click on a server side image map the form will be submitted and the coordinates you clicked on will be included in the data.

If you want a reset button that is an image use:

```
<button type="reset"><img src="..." alt="..."></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The image type is like a **submit button**.

You have to take `type="reset"` and style your button with css.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type = "reset" value = "" class = "btnResetClass" />
```

Your, btnResetClass will have Css Setting for background image to be set by you.

Comment: The image (presumably) informs the user what the button does. It is content, not style and should not be a background image.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `type="reset"`.

[This jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/G3qu8/1/) would be better.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
    <div>
        <label>
            First Name: <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" size="30" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
           Company Name: <input id="company_name" name="company_name" type="text" size="30" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>
            Email: <input id="email"  type="text" name="email" size="30" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="" title="Submit" />
    <input id="reset" type="reset" value="" title="Reset" />
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
#submit, #reset {
    border: none;
    width: 64px;
    height: 48px
}
#submit {
    background: url('images/submit.png')
}
#reset {
    background: url('images/reset.png')
}
```

Comment: Background images are a presentational tool, they aren't appropriate for communicating content to the user. The alt attribute doesn't apply to inputs that are not of type image.

Comment: @Quentin - Thanks for that, I forgot to change `alt` to `title`. I will update my post.